# Searching via gmail api for schemas

Tags: google-schemas

I'm trying to search for any emails that have cards in, however you don't appear to be able to filter using the raw html.

Is there a way of doing this? ideally i'd like to be able to just get back a list of all emails that have events in

many thanks

Dan

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Hi Abielita, Im using:

https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/USERNAME/messages?q=FILTER&access_token=TOKEN

In the raw content of the emails i see this:

<script type="application/ld+json">
 { "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "EventReservation", "reservationNumber": "XXXX", ... } </script>

i'd like to search for emails with these blocks. The specfication for the email markup is here:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation

but you dont seem to be able to search the email for html tags. Is there another way to get these events?